# Vue.js not working in one of my cshtml pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core, razor

I am developing a site using NET Core 3 and VueJS, I have a login page:

```
@page
@model project.Web.Pages.Accounts.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "User Login - ";
    Layout = "../Shared/_Layout";
}

<!-- add class=modal-->
<div id="app">

<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="columns is-centered">
            <div class="column is-12">
                <div class="card auth-card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="login-form is-grouped-centered">
                            <form method="post">
                                <p class="login-form__title subtitle">Sign In or Register</p>
                                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="has-text-danger"></div>
                                <div class="login-form__field field">
                                    <div class="login-form__email-group form-row">
                                        <label class="login-form__email-label" asp-for="Input.Email">My Email</label>
                                        <input class="login-form__input control input" asp-for="Input.Email" id="email-input" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" required maxlength="255" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="has-text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="login-form__title subtitle">Are you an existing customer?</p>
                                <div class="login-form__radio-group">
                                    <input type="radio" class="login-form__radio-group-radio radio" @@click="setPasswordDisabled(true)" name="new_account" value="1" id="signin_new_customer">
                                    <label for="signin_new_customer">No, sign me up.</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="login-form__field login-form__radio-group">
                                    <input type="radio" class="login-form__radio-group-radio radio" @@click="setPasswordDisabled(false)" name="new_account" value="0" id="signin_existing_customer" checked>
                                    <label for="signin_existing_customer">Yes, my password is</label>
                                    <div class="login-form__radio-group">
                                        <input class="login-form__input control input" asp-for="Input.Password" id="auth-password" required />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="has-text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field has-text-right">
                                    <a href="#">Forgotten your password?</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="login-form__submit">
                                    <input v-if="!isNewAccount" class="login-form__submit-button button is-success" type="submit" name="name" value="Sign In" />
                                    <a v-if="isNewAccount" class="login-form__submit-button button is-success" asp-page="/Accounts/Register">Sign Up</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close" @@click="toggleModal()"></button>
</div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/js/login.js"></script>
}
```

And then I have this script in login.js:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        isNewAccount: false
    },
    methods: {
        setPasswordDisabled(value) {
            document.getElementById("auth-password").disabled = value;

            value === true ? this.isNewAccount = true : this.isNewAccount = false;
        },
        toggleModal() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

            modal.classList.toggle("is-active");
        }
    }
});
```

When I open the network tab I can see the Login.js has been loaded, but It doesn't hit the functions in there, I have set some console.logs in the js file and it looks dead, nothing happens.

I also tried wrapping Login.cshml markup into a div id="app" but it doesn't solve my issue, I have no errors/warnings in the console, I literally have not a clue what is going on. Its quite frustrating, I can see the property isNewAccount showing up in vue dev tools but its value never changes when I click the radiobuttons, its always false, and also it doesn't even know whats the value of it in the Login Page as it still showing both buttons, which is totally wrong as I'm clearly adding there v-ifs to show one or another depending on that prop. Has anyone had this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After so many hours I realized I had multiple instances of vue app (only one instance of vue app is allowed), that was causing the issue, removing the div id="app" solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use v-model for change your data

```
<div class="login-form__radio-group">
    <input type="radio" class="login-form__radio-group-radio radio" v-model:"isNewAccount" name="new_account" id="signin_new_customer">
    <label for="signin_new_customer">No, sign me up.</label>
</div>
```

Also you need use type="checkbox" instead of type="radio"

Use name="" or id="" for describe you style for elements. it will logical right